# skipping a route with vert.x

Tags: clojure, vert.x

I'm just checking out `vert.x`, in particular the clojure examples. I'm trying to figure out how to skip a route after I've matched it. My use case is writing a static file handler. I'd like to put it first in the route chain (a `route/get` with a match-everything regex), and do a file exists check under some static file root, and if there is no file there, then I want to check for other defined routes that match.

I was hoping I could just return `nil` from the route handler function, but that ends up throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The usual approach is to try to match more specific routes first and go for the catch-all by default later. Why do you need to it that way? You could also wrap the rest of your routes with a kindof `file-exists?` wrapper function that would by-pass the normal behaviour in that case, not the ideal solution but should work.

Comment: I guess I'm used to the expressjs notion of routes as middleware. I ended up doing as you suggest, and then the static file handler also serves as the 404 handler.